# SQL Server: Duplicate a record to another instance when added..?

Tags: sql-server, dns

I have an SQL Server database with some transaction tables. A payment request is created in one table, and transactions are recorded in another table when payment requests are processed.

I'm moving this system from one server to another, which will involve changing the DNS for the domain to point to the new server.

I can copy the system across (to the new server) and get it working, and copy across the database. The obvious problem is that updating DNS can take a while, so at some unknown point in time customers will be switched from the old server to the new.

Is there an easy way, within SQL Server, or via some tools, to trigger an insert/update to the new server whenever an insert/update happens on the old server - to keep them in sync..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, and much better than triggers. It is called replication. Check this out to get stared [SQL Server Replication Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-tutorials)